# Cómo Multiplicar un solo elemento de una tupla por un número entero ingresado por teclado

Tags: python, while, float, print, else

Estoy tratando de realizar una instrucción que permita multiplicar por separado los elementos de números decimales contenidos en dos tuplas diferentes usando como multiplicador un número entero ingresado por pantalla.
Logro que la instrucción requiera tanto el tipo bono representado por las dos tuplas, así como la cantidad del precio del bono representado por la posición de los elementos de las dos tuplas y que se ingrese la cantidad de en cualquiera de los dos casos sin embargo sin que se realice la multiplicación y solo presenta la instrucción opcional en caso de no ingresar el valor requerido.
¿Alguna idea?

```
prompt0 = "\nPlease enter the type of bonus: "
prompt1 = "\nEnter the price of bonus: "
prompt2 = "\nEnter the quantity of bonus: "
basic_bonus_1 = (0.01, 0.02, 0.03)
basic_bonus_2 = (0.04, 0.05, 0.06)
bono1 = basic_bonus_1
bono2 = basic_bonus_2
bono1_0 = bono1[0]
bono1_1 = bono1[1]
bono1_2 = bono1[2]
bono2_0 = bono2[0]
bono2_1 = bono2[1]
bono2_2 = bono2[2]
while True:
    type_bonus = tuple(input(prompt0))
    price_bonus = (input(prompt1))
    quantity = int(input(prompt2))
    if type_bonus == 'quit':
        break
    elif type_bonus == bono1 and price_bonus == bono1_0:
        print("El precio a pagar por el tipo de bono elegido es: ", bono1[0] * quantity)
    elif type_bonus == bono1 and price_bonus == bono1_1:
        print("El precio a pagar por el tipo de bono elegido es: ", bono1[1] * quantity)
    elif type_bonus == bono1 and price_bonus == bono1_2:
        print("El precio a pagar por el tipo de bono elegido es: ", bono1[2] * quantity)
    elif type_bonus == bono2 and price_bonus == bono2_0:
        print("El precio a pagar por el tipo de bono elegido es: ", bono2[0] * quantity)
    elif type_bonus == bono2 and price_bonus == bono2_1:
        print("El precio a pagar por el tipo de bono elegido es: ", bono2[1] * quantity)
    elif type_bonus == bono2 and price_bonus == bono2_2:
        print("El precio a pagar por el tipo de bono elegido es: ", bono2[2] * quantity)
    else:
        print("Sorry, this value is not vadid!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo poco que entiendo de este programa es que existen 2 tuplas con bonos que representan unos precios. Hay que indicar por teclado qué bono se quiere aplicar, y si el bono existe en alguna de las 2 tuplas entonces multiplicarlo por la cantidad. ¿No?

Si es así como describí, entonces no es necesaria la primera pregunta, ya que Python puede buscar en cada tupla para saber qué bono está aplicando con la instrucción `in`. Ejemplo:

```py
>>> bonos = (0.01, 0.02, 0.03)
>>> 0.02 in bonos
True
```

Entonces el código se puede reducir al siguiente. Cambié los textos de salida para que describa de qué grupo de bonos se seleccionó, pero los puedes poner como quieras.

```py
basic_bonus_1 = (0.01, 0.02, 0.03)
basic_bonus_2 = (0.04, 0.05, 0.06)
while True:
    price_bonus = input("\nEnter the price of bonus (or quit): ")
    if price_bonus == 'quit':
        break
    price_bonus = float(price_bonus)
    quantity = int(input("\nEnter the quantity of bonus: "))
    if price_bonus in basic_bonus_1:
        total = price_bonus * quantity
        print("Bono elegido: 1, precio a pagar:", total)
    elif price_bonus in basic_bonus_2:
        total = price_bonus * quantity
        print("Bono elegido: 2, precio a pagar:", total)
    else:
        print("Sorry, this value is not valid!!!")
```

Comment: Hola, esa es mas o menos la idea, las tuplas representan el precio de dos grupo de bonos diferentes, la opción que presentas permite incluir el precio contenido en cada una de las tuplas, sin embargo, previamente debe permitir incluir el tipo de bono que está representado por cada una de las tuplas, y una vez seleccionada entonces incluir el precio, Por ejemplo, el usuario tendría la opción de primero seleccionar el basic_Bonus_1 o el basicc_bonus_2 y una vez seleccionado uno de ellos entonces sí incluir el precio. No se si me explico. Alguna idea? Gracias anticipadas...

Comment: Muchas gracias aeportugal, tu aporte fue de mucha ayuda....